# Change text within a tag on mouseover

Tags: javascript

I have defined a tag in which on mouseover i am changing the text within the a tag

```
<a class="bid-addwatchlist add-logout" href="/users/login" onmouseover="changeText(this)" onmouseout="sameText(this)"><span style="font-size: 32px; line-height: 18px;">+</span><span style="font-size: 14px; float: left;">Add to watchlists</span></a>

<script>
    function changeText(theTag){
        theTag.innerHTML = '<span style="font-size: 1.7em; text-align:center; line-height:50px;">Login</span>';
    }

    function sameText(theText){
        theText.innerHTML = '<span style="font-size: 32px; line-height: 18px;">+</span><span style="font-size: 14px; float: left;">Add to watchlists</span>';
    }
</script>
```

I have given the following css for this a tag to make it look like a box

```
.bid-addwatchlist{
    background-color : #32679B;
    border-radius : 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    color : #FFFFFF;
    cursor : pointer;
    float : left;
    height : 56px;
    line-height : 14px;
    padding-top : 4px;
    text-decoration : none;
    width : 76px;
    margin-left : 11px;
}
```

It is working fine but the problem i am facing is when i do mouseover the text changes to login and if i click on the login text nothing is happening whereas if i click on other side areas it is working. I am not understanding the problem why this is happening and what i need to do now so that if i click on the login text it works. Please suggest what i need to do or this is because the login text is not within the a tag. All i need to do is i want to change the text within the a tag onmouseover and consequently it should work.

I have also tried this, defined the click event in the span for the text, but not working

```
function changeText(theTag){
        theTag.innerHTML = '<span style="font-size: 1.7em; text-align:center; line-height:50px;" onclick=\'window.location="/users/login"\'>Login</span>';
    }
```

**Note:** The text is just a normal link

Comment: what is the code that you are using, for 'onclick' event?

Comment: I have not defined any click event because it just a normal a tag and it opens automatically

Comment: You should put this into a JSFiddle instead of just showing us some code. It would make your question a lot easier to answer since we can test different methods using your code

Comment: Here, I made one: http://jsfiddle.net/WwM5g/ You should add that to your question so people can help you more easily

Comment: Thanks Mark for putting my code in JDFiddle

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here you go, fixed it ;)

http://jsfiddle.net/WwM5g/2/

I didn't use onmouseover and onmouse out, instead I used the .hover jQuery event.

Answer (score 0):

I think you problem is that the text that you put in for the **onMouseOver** isn't bound to the link element since it isn't inside the  when the DOM is parsed. Therefore I would add the link to the **Login** text too.

```
function changeText(theTag){
    theTag.innerHTML = '<span style="font-size: 1.7em; text-align:center; line-height:50px;"><a href="/users/login">Login</a></span>';
}
```

Comment: You sure? It works for me with an additional <a href=""></a> around the LOGIN text, I can click the login button and it goes to /users/login, just the CSS would need some work since it's got the default ugly blue hover and underline.